# onLocationChanged never gets called, even after requesting for updates

Tags: android

**Start Service:**

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.cancel(pi);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 30*1000, pi);
```

**Service:**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    public static double curLat = 0.0;
    public static double curLng = 0.0;
    private LocationManager mgr;
    private String best;
    private Location location;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        best = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        location = mgr.getLastKnownLocation(best);
        if (location != null) {

            dumpLocation(location);
            mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    5 * 1000, 0, this);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
    }

    private void dumpLocation(Location l) {

        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss",
                Locale.ENGLISH);
        String format = s.format(l.getTime());
        //The above time is always 21/03/2013:09:53:41 which is more than a week old
        curLat = l.getLatitude();
        curLng = l.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //This never seems to be called
        dumpLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}
```

Every 30 secs the service is being called, but the `requestLocationUpdates` never seems to call `onLocationChanged`. And when I checked the time of the `lastKnownLocation` its a week old.

Applications like foursquare, local, maps etc gives the current location with GPS disabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: On a sidenote: the location update can return null Location. Be sure to handle it...

Comment: are you testing in device or emulator ? is your GPS enabled ? are you testing it outside like open sky environment ?

Comment: @Warpzit, Yeah. But I am getting a location. Which I dump and get the timestamp.

Comment: @Lucifer I am testing it on a device. GPS is disabled. I am testing it in a room. I tried switching on the GPS and get the location with GPS_PROVIDER. which gives me accurate location. But other applications are able to give correct location without GPS.

Comment: Also, since the other applications got the current location, `getLastKnowLocation` should have returned me that location, instead of giving a week old location.

Comment: Simple suggestion, Enable the GPS, go out side the room. Reason, `OnLocationChanged()` method will called when your current location gets changed from the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to move from somewhere with your device because onLocationChange only called if the location was change. And the network location was approximate near by 1000-2000 meter so need to check on street where the location was change and getting the new location. If you used gps then it will giving you accurate but it also nearby 20-30 meter after fixed all it.

Comment: +1, But Not fully agree with your meter calculation, because when i use NETWORK_PROVIDER, it gives result even with 5 meters, but the main thing is the change the location ( moving ).

Comment: Yes, but every other application is able to give the exact location(without GPS and without moving). Actually on other device though the location is not changed, everytime the service is called(30 secs) onLocationChanged is called and the TimeStamp is current time.

Comment: I tried restarting the device. Now every 30 secs onLocationChanged is called even without moving and the new location is like 56m accurate, 55m accurate etc.. with tiny change in lat lng. May be it has something to do with the device. But other apps make me wonder how they could get the location. Also might encounter the same issue some time later. Any idea how to solve such cases?